# How to get the query string from a dynamic API routes in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, axios

I have a file API structure as such: `app/api/workspaces[id]/route.js`

```js
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
  console.log("CATEGORY ID", req.query);
  try {
    // I simplified this part, but in the project, I'm fetching the data using Prisma to Supabase
    const tasks = [];
    return NextResponse.json(tasks, { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: `Could not fetch workspaces: ${err}` },
      { status: 500 },
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm calling this API from my FE:

```js
  const { data: tasks, isLoading: isTasksLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: [`tasks-${params.id}`],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/workspaces/${params.id}`);
      return response.data;
    },
  });
```

In `route.js` I tried to `console.log(req.query)` but I'm getting `undefined`. What am I missing?

## UPDATE

Turns out, I have to use the second argument of the GET method as such:

```js
export async function GET(req, context: any) {
    const { id } = context.params;
}
```

I am however, not too sure what's the type of this `context`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments), Next.js passes to API handler a second object as parameter, which contains a `params` key where the slug will be.

But you should specify the type yourself. Also, the type of the request passed is `NextRequest`, not `NextApiRequest` (the type used for API routes in the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router):

```
// app/api/workspaces[id]/route.js

import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  context: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  const { id } = context.params;
}
```

Comment: I'm a lil bit confused on `NextRequest` and `NextApiRequest` (Sorry I'm quite new to Next), but I read somewhere that, usually we use `NextApiRequest` in api routes?

Comment: Woops, nevermind, I saw someone commented regarding this:  
- NextApiRequest is the type you use in the pages router "API Routes"  
- NextRequest is the type you use in the app router "Route handlers"

Comment: Indeed. I have added this info in the answer for future readers. Gave a good day !